# Setup multiple displays with a single video card and HDMI connections

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I'm setting up a showroom with 4 displays running 2 different ad campaigns (2 by 2).

Some displays will be placed far from the (Windows) machine and I was thinking using HDMI amplified cables up to 30 meters to connect them.

Since they are grouped 2 by 2 I could also buy a couple of 2x1 HDMI splitters.

Given that I need to run 2 HDMI displays plus, probably, another display to setup campaigns from the backoffice.

**So drive 3 different displays — 2 x HDMI + 1 x *whatever* — simultaneously with a single videocard**.

Our vendor proposed us an **[AMD Radeon™ HD 6670](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6670/pages/amd-radeon-hd-6670-overview.aspx#2)**, reding specifications I see

> Native support for up to 4 simultaneous displays

But giving a look to video card pictures I can't understand if I will really be able to connect everything or I'll need some adapter (other than HDMI 2x1 splitterrs).

Any advice welcome.